# Security Key and Boilerplate

Tags: craft3, security

We have set up a Craft 3 installation with composer to serve as boilerplate for a number of upcoming projects. The installation sits in a private git repository and the plan is to clone it when we start a new project.

Everything works fine, but since new projects will spawn from the boilerplate, the Security Key is the same for all of them - which probably is a bad idea.

Is there a way to assign a new security key when we clone the boilerplate for a new project? Are there other security considerations to take into account?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the `craft setup/security-key` console command after cloning the repo.  That'll generate a security key for that Craft install and put it in the local `.env` file.

Or for that matter, `craft setup` will run the whole setup process (database credeitials, security key, etc.).

> Are there other security considerations to take into account?

Keep your `craft/config/license.key` out of the repo so that a new one is generated for each cloned site.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot, also for the hint about the license key.